# Неверный вывод результатов: Counter считает каждый символ дважды

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, counter

```
import re #библиотека для работы с регулярными выражениями
import collections
frequency = {} #пустой словарь
document_text = open('text.txt', 'r') #открываем файл на чтение
text_string = document_text.read().lower() #убираем капс
c = collections.Counter(text_string)
for word in text_string:
    c[word] += 1
print(c)
```

Данный скрипт подсчитывает количество повторений каждого символа в файле, но почему то подсчитывает не верно. Результат в 2 раза больше, чем истинные значения. Где я ошибся?

Используется Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часть

```
for word in text_string:
    c[word] += 1
```

бесполезная, так как `Counter` сам делает все что нужно.

Comment: Да, именно в этом и было дело. Уже сам разобрался, но все-равно, спасибо вам)